# Create and write a file into hdfs from my local machine

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have two systems connected in the network. One is hdfs running. I want to create a file and write data from my another machine.

```
  package myorg;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.net.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

  public class Write1{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
            try{
                    System.out.println("Starting...");
                    Path pt=new Path("hdfs://10.236.173.95:8020/user/jfor/out/gwmdfd");
                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                    BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(pt,true)));
                                               // TO append data to a file, use fs.append(Path f)
                    String line;
                    line="Disha Dishu Daasha dfasdasdawqeqwe";
                    System.out.println(line);
                    br.write(line);
                    br.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("File not found");
            }
    }
```

}

I compiled it using

```
   javac -classpath hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar -d Write1/ Write1.java
```

Created a jar using

```
  jar -cvf Write1.jar -C Write1/ .
```

Run command

```
  hadoop jar Write1.jar myorg.Write1
```

If i run this, i am getting

```
 starting...
 File not found
```

What could be the reason? If i run this program, in my hadoop machine, it works fine [I replaced ip with localhost].

Error is at BufferedWriter line. It says "File Not found". what does it mean? I used `fs.creat`. Then it should create if it doesn't exist. Isn't?

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://10.72.40.68:8020/user/jfor/..... expected localhost:8020                                                   

 So i modified the following line

 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://<ip>:8020"),new Configuration());

It says Connection refused. What could be the reason
```

Comment: IP not resolved maybe

Comment: ping to ip works and traceroute to ip works. What else should i do?

Comment: hadoop nodes interact through ssh and since localhost was probably already qualified to access itself without authorization, it worked fine, while your remote machine (the one you're running this java program from) is not qualified yet

Comment: So Do i need to enable passwordless ssh?

Comment: No, It is not working if i give ip instead localhost in the localhost itself

Comment: try to connect to hdfs host through ssh and add this remote host you're connecting from, into the list of authorized hosts list on hdfs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70761/discussion-between-gops-ab-and-mangusta).

Comment: 8020 is not ht HDFS default port, are you aware of that? Furthermore make sure that the port is not blocked by the firewall.

Comment: i can ping to the host. how do i ensure that port is not blocked